# Get ERC721 token total supply using web3.js

Tags: web3js, erc-721

I created a simple contract which basically does nothing but mints new ERC721 tokens. The solidity code for it is as follows:

```
struct Monster {
        string name;
        uint level;
        uint attackPower;
        uint defensePower;
    }

Monster[] public monsters;
function createToken(string _name, address _to) public{
        require(owner == msg.sender);
        uint id = monsters.length;
        monsters.push(Monster(_name, 1, 100, 100));
        _mint(_to, id);
    }
```

I invoked the `createToken` method serveral times and created a token named `testToken` and sent it to my metamask wallet account. I can see the token in metamask.
The contract is deployed on `ropsten` network and I have the contract address.

Now, I want to use `web3.js` to simply check this balance from my account (metamask wallet). I am trying to use this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/erc721 for the abi.

I have the following code:

```
const { MintableNonFungibleToken } = require('erc721');
var abi = MintableNonFungibleToken;
var contractAddress = '0x17b95748b3da7f1c4fbf665b8340b851cec7b856';
var token = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(contractAddress);
console.log(token.balanceOf(address).toNumber());
```

I get the correct token count here. However, I could not find any method `token.decimals()` like in ERC20 contract.

1. Does it mean I can just use `token.balanceOf(address).toNumber()` to find the token count?
2. How do I identify the tokenId of these tokens so I can query more information about the token?
3. How do I execute `totalSupply()`? 
   I tried token `token.totalSupply().toNumber()`. However, the value is always 0.

PS: I haven't implemented `totalSupply()`. I am trying to write generic APIs to query ERC721 contracts and get information, so I am looking for something from standard specs from ERC721 instead of depending on the developer to write specific functions in contracts.

Comment: Have you implemented the `totalSupply()` function in your ERC721 contract? Is it getting updated when you call `createToken()`?

Comment: If I haven't implemented it, how do I get the total tokens?

Answer (score 3):

A [compliant ERC-721 token](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) will have a `totalSupply` method implemented, eg

```
function totalSupply() public view returns (uint) {
    return monsters.length;
}
```

Your contract will need to implement that method to comply with the spec

Comment: I can write that, but I was wondering if there is any ERC721 standard API which allows me to get the total number of tokens. I want to create generic wrapper apis to query erc721 tokens, so I don't want to depend on the contract content, but want to be a part of the standard ERC721 spec.

Comment: ["We have adopted ...totalSupply...semantics from the ERC-20 specification"](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721)

Comment: ok, thanks. How about questions 1 and 2?

Comment: Please note that to be compliant with the ERC-721 standard a contract *doesn't need* to implement the `totalSupply` function. However, there is an *optional* extension, called the enumeration extension, which expects you to implement a `totalSupply` function. All of this information can be found in the aforementioned links.

Comment: Is there a way of knowing how many tokens are left to mint using ERC721? This would be `maxSupply` - `totalSupply`.